# Extra parameters passed to parent construct error after upgrade

Tags: magento2

After upgrading Magento from 2.3.1 to 2.3.3, while running `di:compile`, it throws following error.

```
Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $messageFactory, $emailMessageInterfaceFactory, $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory, $mimePartInterfaceFactory, $addressConverter. 
File: /vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Queue/TransportBuilder.php
Total Errors Count: 1
```

Comment: are you extending/instantiating ```module-newsletter/Model/Queue/TransportBuilder```?

Comment: also, running a ```magento se:up``` before ```magento se:di:co``` may help as it is doing a bit of clean-up.

Comment: Thanks @Radu : Tried , no improvement.

Comment: Can you please the complete error there is a chance that some custom module is extending class TransportBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem while upgrading from 2.2.7 to 2.3.4.
I removed all the given extra parameters from the parent::__construct function from the file, and it compiled successfully.
Not sure if this was the correct way.